# Symfony: services and Rich Domain Models

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

For Symfony projects using Doctrine ORM, I'm used to Anemic Domain Models, with business logic handled in Symfony services. For projects involving heavy business logic, I'm wondering if using Rich Domain Models (which I'm not familiar with) would not be a better solution. **I'm not looking for a comparison of RDM vs ADM, as there is already plenty of resources available online to figure out pros and cons of each solution.** I'm rather wondering if RDM are suited for Symfony projects. To make my mind, I would like a glimpse of how I should implement RMD in a real world application.

The main questions I have are:

- Does RDM really suit Symfony philosophy and best practices?
- Does RDM not break the SOLID principle by having models doing too much?
- How dependencies are managed by the models?

I'll give a theoretical example to express my concerns in a clearer way.

*Lets say we are working on a REST API. We want to implement an user registration. The user registration relies on an external service provider (using an API) and the user creation should result in the creation of some other related entities (we will use a Dummy entity here) and the populate of ElasticSearch indexes in an asynchronous manner using Symfony Messenger.*

The happy flow would look like this:

1. Validation of the request body
2. Call to the external service provider API to create the user on their side
3. Insertion of the user data in database
4. Create user related entities
5. Populate the ElasticSearch indexes
6. Send a confirmation email to the user

> For practical reasons, the code below is simplified and therefore may not be 100% accurate nor functional. It only aims to demonstrate the differences between the two designs.

**Anemic Domain Model implementation**

```
<?php

// src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

class User
{
    private $id;

    private $externalId;

    private $email;

    private $plainPassword;

    private $password;

    private $lastName;

    private $firstName;

    // Include more properties, getters and setters, ...
}
```

```
<?php

// src/Service/UserRegistrationService.php

namespace App\Service;

class UserRegistrationService
{
    private $passwordEncoder;

    private $externalProviderClient;

    private $em;

    private $bus;

    private $mailer;

    private $elasticSearch;

    private $dummyService;

    public function __construct(PasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder, ExternalProviderClient $externalProviderClient, EntityManager $em, MessageBusInterface $bus, Mailer $mailer, ElasticSearchService $elasticSearch, DummyService $dummyService)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        $this->externalProviderClient = $externalProviderClient;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->bus = $bus;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->elasticSearch = $elasticSearch;
        $this->dummyService = $dummyService;
    }

    public function register(User $user): User
    {
        $password = $this->passwordEncoder->encode($user->getPlainPassword());
        $externalId = $this->externalProviderClient->registerUser([
            'email' => $user->getEmail(),
            'firstName' => $user->getFirstName(),
            'lastName' => $user->getLastName(),
        ]);

        $user
            ->setExternalId($externalId)
            ->setPassword($password)
            ->setPlainPassword(null)
        ;

        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();

        $this->bus->dispatch(new UserMessage($user));

        return $user;
    }

    public function completeRegistration(User $user)
    {
        $dummy = $this->dummyService->createUserDependencies($user);

        $this->elasticSearch->populateUser($user);
        $this->elasticSearch->populateDummy($dummy);

        $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmail($user);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

// src/Controller/UserController.php

namespace App\Controller;

class UserController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request, UserRegistrationService $userRegistrationService, Serializer $serializer)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            // Process errors
        }

        $userRegistrationService->register($user);

        return $this->serializer->serialize($user);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the business logic relies on a lot of services, and this is just one of the tiniest and most basic functionality the API has to offer.

**Rich Domain Model implementation**

```
<?php

// src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

class User
{
    private $id;

    private $externalId;

    private $email;

    private $plainPassword;

    private $password;

    private $lastName;

    private $firstName;

    // Include more properties, getters and setters, ...
}
```

```
<?php

// src/Model/UserRegistration.php

namespace App\Model;

class UserRegistration
{
    private $email;

    private $plainPassword;

    private $lastName;

    private $firstName;

    private function __construct(string $email, string $plainPassword, string $lastName, string $firstName)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    // Getters

    public static function createFromRequest(Validator $validator, Request $request)
    {
        $requestData = $request->request->all();
        $userRegistration = new self(requestData['email'], $requestData['plainPassword'], $requestData['lastName'], $requestData['firstName']);

        $violations = $validator->validate($userRegistration);
        if (count($violations) > 0) {
            throw new \Exception(); // handle errors
        }

        return $userRegistration;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

// src/Model/User.php

namespace App\Model;

class User
{
    private $id;

    private $externalId;

    private $email;

    private $oassword;

    private $lastName;

    private $lastName;

    private function __construct(string $id, string $externalId, string $email, string $password, string $lastName, string $firstName)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->externalId = $externalId;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    // Getters

    public static function createFromUserRegistration(Validator $validator, PasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder, ExternalProviderClient $externalProviderClient, EntityManager $em, MessageBusInterface $bus, UserRegistration $userRegistration)
    {
        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($userRegistration->getPlainPassword());
        $externalId = $externalProviderClient->registerUser([
            'email' => $userRegistration->getEmail(),
            'firstName' => $userRegistration->getFirstName(),
            'lastName' => $userRegistration->getLastName(),
        ]);

        $userEntity = (new \App\Entity\User())
            ->setExternalId($externalId)
            ->setEmail($userRegistration->getEmail())
            ->setPassword($password)
            ->setLastName($userRegistration->getLastName())
            ->setFirstName($userRegistration->getFirstName())
        ;

        $em->persist($userEntity);
        $em->flush();

        $id = ;


        $user = self::buildFromUserEntity($validator, $userEntity);

        $bus->dispatch(new UserMessage($user));

        return $user;
    }

    public static function buildFromUserEntity(Validator $validator, \App\Entity\User $userEntity)
    {
        $user = new self(
            $userEntity->getId(),
            $userEntity->getExternalId(),
            $userEntity->getEmail(),
            $userEntity->getPassword(),
            $userEntity->getLastName(),
            $userEntity->getFirstName()
        );

        $violations = $validator->validate($user);
        if (count($violations) > 0) {
            throw new \Exception(); // handle errors
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function completeRegistration(EntityManager $em, ElasticSearch $elasticSearch, Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $dummy = new Dummy($this);
        $dummy->save($em);

        $this->populateElasticSearch($elasticSearch);
        $dummy->populateElasticSearch($elasticSearch);

        $this->sendConfirmationEmail($mailer);
    }

    public function populateElasticSearch(ElasticSearch $elasticSearch)
    {
        $this->elasticSearch->populate($this);
    }

    public function sendConfirmationEmail(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmail($this);
    }

    public function serialize(Serializer $serializer)
    {
        return $serializer->serialize($user);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

// src/Controller/UserController.php

namespace App\Controller;

class UserController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request, Validator $validator, PasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder, ExternalProviderClient $externalProviderClient, EntityManager $em, MessageBusInterface $bus, Serializer $serializer)
    {
        $userRegistration = UserRegistration::createFromRequest($validator, $request);
        $user = User::createFromUserRegistration($validator, $passwordEncoder, $externalProviderClient, $em, $bus, $userRegistration);

        return $user->serialize($serializer);
    }
}
```

The main problems I see with this implementation are:

- Duplicate code between user RMD and entity
- Models will get bigger and bigger with each new functionality
- Managing dependencies can quickly be a mess

What are your thoughts on this? Is there things I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are aware, that this is (obviously) mostly opinion-based, thus you might agree or disagree with it.

I think you have a major misunderstanding of what the Rich Domain Model and the Anemic Domain Model is. But let's start with a few assumptions:

In my understanding, entities in symfony (more precisely in Doctrine's ORM) already are models in most cases. Thus having an additional `User` model is just unnecessary. And even if you wanted to split, I wouldn't put the exact same fields into the model, but just have the entity as a field. If you happen to copy all of the entities functions to the model, you're doing it wrong. Since by default all fields of an entity should be private, there is no reason to not treat it as a model. (I mean, it already works with objects and not their ids in relations...).

A `User` model/entity should never be concerned with sending emails, IMHO, because it breaks separation of concerns. Instead there should be something modelling the process in which the email is sent. I find [this article](https://thevaluable.dev/anemic-domain-model/) describes rather cleanly, how this works. Pay attention to the changes to Shipment and to the CheckoutService -> Checkout.

Ironically, your "Anemic Domain Model"s `UserRegistrationService` is quite good. The user entity is a bit anemic in that implementation though and it should probably validate the User entity, but apart from that, the service could be renamed to `UserRegistration` and would fit *very* fine into RDM. (I agree, that the validation is already being done by the form (a convenience really), but there might be validations that are not about the consistency of the user in itself, but about the user as part of the collection of users in your database / model, or something else).

To summarize: In my view, Symfony can do RDM, and rather well. But the real crux (as always) is to actually choose/design the best model.

Essentially: Anemic means you don't have *one* place where all things are consistently done, but instead is split in a way which *risks consistency/integrity* or split separation of concerns to independent units. RDM on the contrary keeps it clustered in semantically sensible places. It doesn't change the fact, that you still want separation of concerns!

Now to answer your questions:

> Does RDM really suit Symfony philosophy and best practices?

why not. depends on the modelling though, which might be adapted to fit Symfony's best practices.

> Does RDM not break the SOLID principle by having models doing too much?

not generally, if done right. Your implementation definitely does break SOLID, but RDM doesn't have to. Nobody is saying that having a UserRegister and UserCancel and UserUpdate service/model would be wrong. RDM is about keeping the stuff that semantically belongs together in a business process/unit also together in code (which doesn't negate separation of concern or single purpose).

> How dependencies are managed by the models?

Since in my view, business processes are models, and will act as services, dependencies are just as they are handled in services. Entities on the other hand should not need services ever*. (there might be some *very very* special circumstances, in which case you might want to actually have a service (a factory maybe) that manages the creation/updates of the entity)

> What are your thoughts on this? Is there things I am doing wrong?

your implementation is, let's say 'unfortunate' in that it isn't RDM in my understanding and (as you realize yourself) breaks SOLID all over the place. So yes to the second part of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Based on it, I can say one of my difficulties is that I had trouble seeing models as something else than data holder: from my understanding, a model should never have been a service, hence the mess with the properties and the dependencies. I probably confuse and mix concepts of models and entities too (not to mention my misunderstanding of ADM and RDM, as you rightly pointed out). The article you linked completed your answer very well. I will have to practice for some times before mastering the subject, but you sure pushed me on the right path.

Comment: One more question though: in your opinion, can multiple related models (say UserRegister, UserUpdate, ...) use the same entity (User), or should concerns be separated in the persistence level as well? I'm thinking of data analysts that can have a harder time fetching the data they need from multiple tables instead of one: even though they have to adapt to the database and not the other way around, if there's no practical reason to not simplify their job, why not do it.

Comment: @Boulzy the User entity is the representation of the user, and everything concerning the user should use the User entity. In my opinion, the UserRegister (if this is seen as one Process) should be short lived anyway and usually not exist at the same time as UserUpdate. But even if they do co-exist, it's reasonable to let both Update and Register access and hold the same User entity (it's even preferred, I would say). Race conditions are a problem, which should receive some attention, but it's almost unrelated to the modeling.

Comment: @Boulzy I think, data analysis is a topic, where you rarely use distinct entities and usually work on databases directly or with the dbal layer and usually stay read-only i.e. side effect free. if the user is the one doing data analysis, there is usually some effort involved in creating interfaces that expose the functionality but don't leak privileged/protected data (like data from other users). it's a difficult topic on its own.